# Using --verbose in multi function python script

Tags: python, verbosity

I want to add a verbose option to my python script but I'm not sure the best way to go about this. My main() function calls a parse_cmdline() function then a process() function. I want to create a function for my verbose option. I'm not sure where I should define my verbose function. Will I have to pass the verbose option from my parse_cmdline() to my process() function? I am looking for the best way to go about this.

Comment: I am already aware of how to parse arguments. I am using argparse. I want to make a function for my verbose option that is clean and easy. Information on how to parse arguments is not helpful.

Comment: Why don't you add that information to your question then? Adding your current code (the part where you parse arguments for example) would have been helpful to illustrate your question better.

Comment: In my question I stated I wanted to create a function for my verbose option but it seems everyone was keen to ignore that part.

Comment: I find your question to be *very* unclear and vague in any case. People don't wilfully ignore parts of a question. If you are getting *3* answers that in your view do not address your question, then something is wrong with your question, I am afraid.

Comment: Nobody even mentioned defining a function for verbose

Comment: But what does `verbose` *mean* in this context? You haven't shared anything about your program, let alone what it outputs, what it'll output more of when you switch on verbose, how you currently pass configuration around.

Comment: be more vebose in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Logging

You basically need a logging module to filter out output depending on the required verbosity. 
That is, every output message gets given a severity level (like `debug` or `warning`), and you can then decide what is the minimum severity level for the messages to be displayed.

You just use the parsed the arguments to decide the required severity level (Basically, the higher the minimum severity level, the less verbose the program is).

## Logbook

I can only recommend the awesome  [`logbook`](http://packages.python.org/Logbook/) module. Using a [`handler`](http://packages.python.org/Logbook/api/handlers.html) whose log `level` is set to the minimum required severity you require will easily solve your issue (e.g. Display only `notice` and higher...).

You will then have to replace calls to `print` in your script with [logging calls](http://packages.python.org/Logbook/quickstart.html#quickstart) `logbook.debug`, `logbook.info`, and so on.

There are a lot of more advanced features in `logbook`, feel free to look around the documentation.

---

Please be aware that, by default, [`logbook` registers a `StderrHandler`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/logbook/blob/master/logbook/__init__.py#L45) and pushes it to the application, you can easily undo that with `logbook.default_handler.pop_application()`.

There are other solutions, as [suggested by the documentation](http://packages.python.org/Logbook/quickstart.html#registering-handlers).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [argh](http://packages.python.org/argh/tutorial.html)?

First import

```
import argh
```

Then you would use something like this to add the option

```
@argh.arg('--verbose', default=False, help='Be more verbose')
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your options with `argparser` and either pass them around or put them in a `global`

Note that you only have to use the `global` keyword when you want to assign to some name in the global scope, not when you just want yo read the value.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`plac`](http://plac.googlecode.com/hg/doc/plac.html). It's an awesome package for commandline parsing, much more inituitive than the built-in `argparse`, in my opinion.